# Restore MSSQL database backup to a new database

Tags: sql-server, backup, restore

I need to make clean database template backup and then generate a new one database with another name, but with backuped content.
Backup script is:

```
sqlcmd -S %DB_HOST% -Q "BACKUP DATABASE %DB_NAME% TO DISK = '%BACKUP_FILE%'"
```

Restore script is:

```
sqlcmd -S %DB_HOST% -Q "RESTORE DATABASE %DB_NAME% FROM DISK = '%BACKUP_FILE%' WITH REPLACE"
```

And it works on the same database name.
But if i backup DB 'ORIGINAL_DB_NAME' and then restore it to 'NEW_DB_NAME' it will raise exception:

```
Msg 1834, Level 16, State 1, Server <HOST>, Line 1
The file '.....\MSSQL\Data\ORIGINAL_DB_NAME.mdf' cannot be overwritten.  It is being used by database 'ORIGINAL_DB_NAME'.
....
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify a new location for the data/log files.

See [this MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186858.aspx), Example D

```
RESTORE DATABASE AdventureWorks2012
FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH NORECOVERY, 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' TO 
'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.mdf', 
      MOVE 'AdventureWorks2012_Log' 
TO 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Data\NewAdvWorks.ldf';
RESTORE LOG AdventureWorks2012
   FROM AdventureWorksBackups
   WITH RECOVERY;
```

Comment: What does the line 'AdventureWorks2012_Data' stand for? Is it the current directory where the data file is or is it a file name or what? Its not clear from your code what it stands for

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid that conundrum using SSMS. Under the Options tab, after you have selected a source for your restore direct the data and log files to either the files you want to overwrite, or point them to the directory you need and name them appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

If you go to Files on the Restore Configuration, make sure that the **Original File Name** is not the same as **Restore As**, that should solve your issue.